# incorrect JSON response from S3 Multiple Objects Delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to delete a list of S3 items but noticed that the response from the API call does not seems correct:

according to the API the [response](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html) should contain the **Deleted** list only in this case:

> **Deleted**
>
> Container element for a successful delete. It identifies the
>   object that was successfully deleted.
>
> Children: Key, VersionId
>
> Type: Container
>
> Ancestor: DeleteResult

delete_json is:

```
{
   'Objects':[
      {
         'Key':'test1'
      },
      {
         'Key':'test2'
      },
      {
         'Key':'test3'
      },
      {
         'Key':'test4'
      }
   ],
   'Quiet':False
}
```

Python code to delete:

```
response = self.client.delete_objects(Bucket=s3_bucket, Delete=delete_json)
```

and the response is:

```
{
   'Deleted':[
      {
         'DeleteMarkerVersionId':'null',
         'Key':'test1',
         'DeleteMarker':True
      },
      {
         'DeleteMarkerVersionId':'null',
         'Key':'test2',
         'DeleteMarker':True
      },
      {
         'DeleteMarkerVersionId':'null',
         'Key':'test3',
         'DeleteMarker':True
      },
      {
         'DeleteMarkerVersionId':'null',
         'Key':'test4',
         'DeleteMarker':True
      }
   ],
   'ResponseMetadata':{
      'HostId':'JDl4XNrK02lfBLXCDDIJjuPXG6tOovOp0dtCv7eMlHc0hGC2L7eSV/wb/XRBFyYQ9mHHzb0O/Yg=',
      'HTTPStatusCode':200,
      'RequestId':'2F2A9FAE7F906B8'
   }
}
```

is it a bug?

Comment: Is this a versioned bucket, or perhaps a bucket that was previously versioned, but that now has versioning suspended?

Comment: its marked as "Versioning is currently suspended on this bucket." , would it matter?

Comment: Unless my comment was just a lucky guess :) then it would matter.  I'll attempt to explain.

Comment: Sorry, but what are you suggesting is a bug? Which part of the output do you think is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have confirmed in comments, this bucket had versioning enabled, and subsequently suspended.

This is not the same thing as a bucket that has never had versioning enabled.  Once a bucket has had versioning enabled, it's always going to be a versioned bucket, but the versioning behavior for new objects, overwrites, and deletes, is different.

From the API documentation, the page you cited:

> Because versioning is enabled on the bucket, Amazon S3 does not delete the object. Instead, it adds a delete marker for this object. The response indicates that a delete marker was added (the DeleteMarker element in the response as a value of true) and the version number of the delete marker it added.

Take that information, then add to it the behavior that necessarily must follow when versioning is suspended.  The version number of the delete marker is null, because that's how delete markers work in versioning suspended buckets.  The delete marker replaces the `null` version of the object, if present, and assumes the id of `null` itself.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingObjectsfromVersioningSuspendedBuckets.html

It also follows that your delete operation may not actually have removed the desired object, if it wasn't the null version of the object.  The object will only appear to have been deleted.

The API response seems correct.